# Split Names in Excel using multiple characters

Tags: excel, string, text, names

I've had some luck modifying formulas I've found on this site to separate names in a spreadsheet but I need some help.  Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve my goal?

I have a "Tenant" column where each row contains from 1 -5 names, separated by commas and "&".

My data is pretty consistent so there is no need for error routines and it looks like these examples with the max # names being 5:

John Doe, Mary Smith, Rachel Reyes & Ben Thompson
or
John Doe & Mary Smith
or
John Doe, Mary Smith & Rachel Reyes

What I really want to do is separate each name into it's own column and then separate each first name into a another column. I would have a total of 5 columns for full names and 5 more for first names for up to 5 max names if that makes sense.

So for this data: John Doe, Mary Smith, Rachel Reyes & Ben Thompson

Column:

```
|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|
John Doe|John|Mary Smith|Mary|Rachel Reyes|Rachel|Ben Thompson|Ben|
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Text to Columns, first using `|` delimiter? Then use some logic and see how to then separate by space.

Comment: Use `Replace` on the string first, replacing any `&` characters with `|` characters, then use `Split`

Comment: I didn't explain this very well.  The | was supposed to just represent an Excel column  :)